# How to improve color consistency of bitmap pictures from native format to target pdf file?

Tags: graphics, color, printing

For the first time I am concerned about proper rendition of pictures for the draft of a document with artistic content. I use the basic macro below to embed the pictures. The pictures are in .jpg format and have embedded ICC profiles. Once in the target pdf, the pictures are noticeably darker than viewed natively. I have made various experiments to identify the source of the problem, and came to the conclusion that:

- native pictures are seen consistently regardless of the software used (Several navigators, Gimp, preview, etc)
- the target pdf is also viewed consistently when viewed from various pdf viewers, navigators, etc. 
  I wonder what can create this situation. Would a conversion  of all pictures into an alternate format prior to compilation help? If yes, which one?

  ```
  \newcommand{\SinglePicture}[3]{%  
  \begin{figure}[#1]
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}\caption*{#3}  
  \end{figure}
  }
  ```

Comment: Maybe [these instructions](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~karlu/div/howto/LaTeX_colour_management.php) or [these](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/making-a-cmyk-pdf/153995) help?

Comment: @Stephan Lehmke The conversion of the images into pdf format, prior to the compilation,as suggested in the first reference you provided, seems to do the trick. I would suggest to edit your comment as an answer.

Comment: could you provide an example image so I could do a side-by-side comparison in my answer?

Comment: Sure but I do not know how to do it on the site. You can mail me privately at yves_paris at aliceadsl.fr and I will send you examples by mail.

Comment: @Stephan Lehmke I am on OSX, (I am not sure the "convert" tool is identical on other sytems) and I did convert all images into pdf with embedding the same profile and a custom gamma:                        convert -density 600 -colorspace sRGB -gamma 1.2  $f ${f%%.*}.pdf                                          This presumably eliminates the drawback of a single paramameter per document. Converting with tha Apple "preview" seems to work without custom settings, but one needs ot convert pictures one by one.

Comment: That is good to hear, but it must really be an effect of your version of `convert`. Trying your invocation on my system with the `Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg` example I was using, I get no effect, the colors are still all wrong after embedding :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I know next to nothing about colour management, but find the subject interesting. I'm confused by some of the stuff below. Maybe someone with more knowledge can shed some light...

By googling, I found two advices on this issue.

**Update:** Based on [michal-h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21)s suggestion that `pdftex` supports adding a color profile to an embedded image, I could work out another solution. See section **Attach Color Profile to Embedded Image** below.

### Convert to PDF

See http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~karlu20/div/howto/LaTeX_colour_management.php

There, the advice is basically to convert the image (including a profile) to PDF and embed the PDF.

To test, I downloaded the example [image with ProPhoto profile](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~karlu20/div/howto/icc/butterfly_ProPhoto.png).

`identify -verbose butterfly_ProPhoto.png` gives

```
Profile-icc: 566 bytes
  Description: SCARSE: Kodak ProPhoto RGB
  Manufacturer: SCARSE: Kodak ProPhoto RGB
  Model: SCARSE: Kodak ProPhoto RGB
  Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2005 Scarse Project
```

so apparently the profile is found by ImageMagick. Then I converted the image with `convert butterfly_ProPhoto.png butterfly_ProPhoto.pdf`. From the docs ImageMagick can cope with color profiles, and `identify -verbose butterfly_ProPhoto.pdf` gives

```
Profile-icc: 2576 bytes
  Description: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
  Manufacturer: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
  Model: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
  Copyright: Copyright Artifex Software 2011
```

So apparently the PDF contains a profile, but it was converted (why?).

Testing the profile embedding with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{butterfly_ProPhoto.png}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{butterfly_ProPhoto.pdf}

\end{document}
```

and viewing with acrobat reader, I don't see a difference:

[image]

Furthermore, the result on my screen looks completely different from [the example PDF given on the linked page](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~karlu/div/howto/icc/table.pdf), so apparently I did something wrong by just using convert.

A further hint `convert` doesn't cut it comes from [this example containing an image with a GBR profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20140714130200/http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flash/quickstart/color_correction_as3/_jcr_content/articlePrerequistes/multiplefiles/node_1279269672685/file.res/color_correction_flash_player.zip).

Converting `Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg` to PDF and viewing in acrobat reader like above gives

[image]

The same is displayed in Acrobat Professional, btw.

*So apparently it is indeed impossible to use `convert` to successfully convert profiled images to PDF for embedding with `pdftex`, though the ImageMagic doc and `identify` results seem to suggest otherwise. Could someone elaborate?*

### Second try: Convert to PDF with Acrobat Professional

Disappointed with no success at all trying to convert to PDF with ImageMagick, I tried the same procedure converting the test images (PNG and JPG) to PDF with the "create PDF" feature of Acrobat professional, and voilá:

[image]

[image]

So I can conclude that converting a profiled image into a PDF with embedded profile indeed works, but not with the ImageMagick based toolchain I've used on my Ubuntu Linux system.

The page I linked to in the beginning mentions that apparently the only tool capable of doing this under Linux is **Scribus** which I have not tried here.

### Embedding a colour profile in the PDF

See http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/making-a-cmyk-pdf/153995

This advice basically is to embed a colour profile in the PDF.

So, taking the GBR example above, I extracted the ICC profile with

```
convert Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg gbr.icm
```

and embedded the profile into the PDF with the following test file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4}  file{gbr.icm}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /OutputIntents [ <<
  /Type /OutputIntent
  /S/GTS_PDFA1
  /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (Adobe GBR (2004))
  /Info(Adobe GBR (2004))
 >> ]
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Peppers_withGBRprofile.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Frustratingly, with acrobat reader on Ubuntu, the PDF displays exactly as (wrongly):

[image]

But in Acrobat Professional, I get the correct display:

[image]

So it seems that embedding a color profile in the PDF does work (on both JPG and PDF inclusions), but not with acrobat reader on Linux.

Furthermore, this "solution" means the embedded profile simply becomes the base profile for the whole document, so one profile will be applied to all images (which do not themselves contain a profile). So embedding both test images (both of which contain different profiles), the result is

[image]

In the color proofing dialog you can also see that the GBR profile is shown as the document profile. This is a further aspect that this advice isn't so useful, because I could assign any other profile right there in the Acrobat dialog (changing the color display of both images accordingly).

### Attach Color Profile to Embedded Image

Based on the advice of [michal-h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21) in his answer I looked into the `pdftex` doc and found that the `\pdfximage` primitive indeed supports a keyword `colorspace` which will associate the corresponding object with the embedded image.

Based on this, I could make the following patch to the `pdftex` driver of the `graphics` package (including example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
  \let\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
  \define@key{Gin}{colorspacefile}{\def\GPT@colorspacefile{#1}}%

  \patchcmd\Gread@@pdftex
  {\pdfximage\GPT@RuleAttr}
  {%
    \ifx\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
     \else
      \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4}  file{\GPT@colorspacefile}%
      \@tempcnta\the\pdflastobj
    \fi
    \pdfximage\GPT@RuleAttr
    \ifx\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
     \else
      colorspace \@tempcnta
    \fi
  }%
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg}\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,colorspacefile={gbr.icm}]{./Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{butterfly_ProPhoto.png}\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,colorspacefile={prophoto.icm}]{./butterfly_ProPhoto.png}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

I got the profiles directly from the images with

```
convert Peppers_withGBRprofile.jpg gbr.icm
convert butterfly_ProPhoto.png prophoto.icm
```

To me, this seems to be the best solution because it allows to associate each image with its own color profile without needing a non-trivial conversion step.

Interestingly, you can see on the test image that it also works with PNG images, although the `pdftex` documentation claims this should not work.

**Note that the "integration" given above is a proof-of-concept only and should not be used for production purposes. First, one should have some "caching" mechanism for color profiles to avoid embedding a profile more than once. Secondly, if the same file should be used with different profiles (as in this example), this could clash with the internal caching mechanism which will embed each image only once. Note the trick with using the `./` filename prefix to make the same file appear as two different files.**

### Conclusions

From this round of tests, I conclude that

1. Converting images to PDF with embedded color profile works, but I couldn't get it to work with `convert` from ImageMagick (version 6.7.7-10). So the number of workable tools for Linux seems to be limited (the linked article mentions Scribus, which I did not try).
2. Embedding an ICC profile in the PDF generated by `pdftex` demonstrably works, but it seems acrobat reader (version 9.5.5) on Ubuntu has problems interpreting such an embedded profile, while Acrobat Professional hasn't. Furthermore, this adds "only" a global profile to the whole PDF document, without a possibility to differentiate between different images.
3. Using the `colorspace` keyword of `\pdfximage`, it is possible to attach a color profile to any embedded image.
4. On the whole, the third alternative seems to be the best solution, because it also works with acrobat reader on Linux, every image can have its own profile, and no rare tool for converting images is required.

Comment: By any chance do you still have the PDF? I tried to generate mine with your code using \pdfximage but it does not work, even with adobe reader 9.5.5 (tested with the one packaged with nixpkgs). The only software that seems to recognize it is the What's app preview of the PDF ^^'

Comment: (ok, I even tried with Adobe on windows, and it is still not working… seems like I definitely did something bad as this file https://www.color.org/version4pdf.pdf is working. I created a new question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709420/why-isnt-the-icc-profile-applied)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in PDF format doesn't suffice that included image contains ICC profile, but this profile must be included as a standalone object and the image must reference this object.

I think there is a low level support for this feature in `pdftex` (but only for jpeg images, regarding to the manual) and `luatex`, but the `graphicx` package doesn't have support for this.

More user friendly (at least for me :)) possibility to include a `icc` profile is using `luatex`'s `img` library. I created small library called `collorspaces.lua`:

```
local m = {}

local colorspaces = {}
local images = {}

function create_profile(filename)
  local icc = pdf.immediateobj("streamfile", filename, [[
/N 3
/Alternate/DeviceRGB]])                   
  local profile = pdf.immediateobj("[/ICCBased "..icc.." 0 R]") 
  return profile
end

function load_image(filename, attributes)
  local exists =images[filename]
  if exists then return exists end
  local profile_file = filename:gsub("[%w]+$","icm")
  local command = "convert ".. filename .." " .. profile_file 
  local conversion_status = os.execute(command)
  local profile = nil
  local img_attr = {filename = filename}
  if conversion_status == 0 then
    local icc_file = io.open(profile_file,"r")
    local icc = icc_file:read("*all")
    icc_file:close()
    local hash = md5.sumhexa(icc)
    profile = colorspaces[hash] 
    if not profile then
      profile = create_profile(profile_file)
    end
    img_attr.colorspace= profile
    colorspaces[hash]=profile 
  end
  local image = img.scan(img_attr)
  images[filename] = image
  return image
end

local function write_image(image)
  return img.write(image)
end

local function include_image(image_name)
  local image = load_image(image_name)
  write_image(image)
end
--load_image("gbr.jpg")
--load_image("rgb.jpg")
m.load_image = load_image
m.write_image = write_image
m.include_image = include_image
return m
```

main function is `load_image`, where `icc` profile is extracted using imagemagick's `convert` utility, then hash of this file is calculated, to prevent multiple inclusions of same profile to the pdf file, and if the profile wasn't used yet, it is included using `create_profile` function. Then the image is loaded. There are two more functions, `write_image` will output the image to the output stream, and `include_image` which load and write image.

Now some sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\pdfcompresslevel=0 

\directlua{%
  cs = require "colorspaces"
}
\def\myinc#1{\mbox{\directlua{cs.include_image "#1"}}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Rgb file without profile\\ 
\myinc{rgb.jpg}

Rgb file with profile\\
\myinc{gbr.jpg}

Rgb file with profile and includegraphics\\
\includegraphics{gbr.jpg}

Resize image\\
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\myinc{gbr.jpg}}
\end{document}
```

You must run it with

```
 lualatex -shell-escape filename
```

otherwise `convert` command couldn't be run!

There are two images, `gbr.jpg` and `rgb.jpg`, these are peppers from Stephan's samples. First contains ICC profile, second doesn't. The result:

[image]

As you can see, there is slight difference in first two images, which were included using our function, third, using `\includegraphics` is completely wrong. Last example shows how to resize the image.

If you doesn't want to use `lualatex`, you can convert your images to `pdf` with this script `imgtopdf.lua`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env texlua
local filename = arg[1]
if not filename then 
    print "Usage imgtopdf filename"
    return false
end

local jobname = filename:gsub("%.%w+$","")

local tpl = [[\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua{cs = require "colorspaces"}
\def\myinc#1{\directlua{cs.include_image "#1"}}
\begin{document}
\myinc{%s}
\end{document}
]]


local lualatex = io.popen("lualatex -shell-escape -jobname="..jobname,"w")
lualatex:write(string.format(tpl,filename))
lualatex:close()
```

Run with

```
texlua imgtopdf.lua imagename
```

Comment: Great solution! And thanks for the hint that `pdftex` supports attaching a profile to an embedded image! Thus I could much enhance my solution :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it prints a really weird result in both Okular and evince, like we cannot even recognize the picture. More details here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709420/why-isnt-the-icc-profile-applied

Comment: Ok, seems like I just need to change `/N 4` to `/N 3` and `Alernate` to `Alternate` as pointed out my Ulrike in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709420/why-isnt-the-icc-profile-applied?noredirect=1#comment1764358_709420

Comment: @tobiasBora thanks, I've fixed the code. I am surprised that it still works otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve stumbled upon this issue recently too, and managed to found two easy workarounds (I’ve used [this file](https://github.com/mpv-player/random-stuff/blob/f95e6c4c91216d66062aab057587b19e10378b24/icc_profiles/BGR-Red-Ducati_WCS-Test-TriState.jpg) for my tests —I couldn’t find the original peppers picture—; the motorcycle is blue without profile, green with it).

First one comes from the fact I was using XeLaTeX before, which actually just works for this. So, a solution could be to convert the file to PDF using `xelatex` to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{file.jpg}
\end{document}
```

and then, include the produced PDF into your LuaLaTeX/pdfLaTeX document, and it should just work.

The second solution I’ve found is to open the picture in [Krita](https://krita.org), and then under `Image > Convert Image Colour Space…`. Then choose `sRGB` as the target profile, and save your file (without including the colour profile). Now it should show correctly even in app not respecting embedded profiles.

Answer (score 0):

## With xelatex (only needed to turn the image to a pdf!)

I actually did not realize directly the great answer of Archange, that is the [only working solution in this thread for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709420/why-isnt-the-icc-profile-applied?noredirect=1#comment1764354_709420): first use `xelatex` (NOT lualatex nor pdflatex) to generate the pdf file using the standalone package and a simple includegraphics, and include then that pdf file. Because it might be tedious to run on many pictures, here is a script that does that automatically and caches the file (requires `-shell-escape`, read documentation of robust-externalize if you do not want to use `-shell-escape`). You might need to copy the .sty file of robust-externalize if you have a not really recent CTAN.

Image (blue if color management is enabled, red/green otherwise):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{robust-externalize} 

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode,
  new preset={icc image xelatex}{
    latex,
    add to preamble={\usepackage{graphicx}},
    use xelatex,
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includegraphicsICC}{D<>{}O{}m}{%
  \cacheMe[
    icc image xelatex,
    add to includegraphics options={#2},
    dependenciesList={#3},
    #1
  ]{\includegraphics{__ROBEXT_WAY_BACK__#3}}
}

\begin{document}

Compare:

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

With:

\includegraphicsICC[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-command-extra-options: "--shell-escape -halt-on-error"
% End:
```

[image]

## With img2pdf

I also found the great tool [img2pdf](https://github.com/myollie/img2pdf) (`nix-shell -p img2pdf` if you use nix) that does also something similar: `img2pdf yourimage.jpg -o yourimage.pdf` will produce a pdf that you can just include:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode,
  new preset={img2pdf}{
    set compilation command={img2pdf "__ROBEXT_WAY_BACK____IMG_SOURCE_FILE__" -o "__ROBEXT_OUTPUT_PDF__"},
    set template={},
    command if no externalization/.code={%
      \robExtDisableTikzpictureOverwrite\evalPlaceholder{\includegraphics[__ROBEXT_INCLUDEGRAPHICS_OPTIONS__]{__IMG_SOURCE_FILE__}}%
    }%
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includegraphicsICC}{D<>{}O{}m}{%
  \cacheMe[
    img2pdf,
    set includegraphics options={#2},
    dependenciesList={#3},
    set placeholder={__IMG_SOURCE_FILE__}{#3},
    #1
  ]{}
}

\begin{document}

Compare:

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

With:

\includegraphicsICC[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-command-extra-options: "--shell-escape -halt-on-error"
% End:
```