# Use localized quotation marks, hyphenation and ponctuation in BibLaTeX using langid for entries title

Tags: biblatex, babel, hyphenation, csquotes

What I get:

> A. Author, « Some article title ? ». Whatever Journal.
>
> B. Buthor, « Un article ? ». Another Journal.

What I would like:

> A. Author, “Some article title?”. Whatever Journal.
>
> B. Buthor, « Un article ? ». Another Journal.

And hyphenation should be language-dependent of course. ;)

`autolang=other` is not an option as it would translate some other parts of the bibliography that I don’t want to be affected.

I’ve stumbled upon [BibLaTeX langid with autolang=hyphen makes csquotes use localized quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396569/biblatex-langid-with-autolang-hyphen-makes-csquotes-use-localized-quotation-mark) and the old behaviour is mostly what I want (with the minor point that I don’t know how it behaved w.r.t. punctuation like question marks above).

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{eng,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Some article title?},
  journal = {Whatever Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {british},
}
@article{fra,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  title = {Un article ?},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {french},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code?

Comment: Sure, added a MNWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

A remark about the punctuation marks. There are two types in your example:

- Punctuation marks in fields, like e.g. the question mark in the title: `{Some article 
  title?}`,
- Punctuation marks created by macros from biblatex, e.g. the colon after the `In:`.

The first type is difficult to adapt to the language with pdflatex as the catcodes are already frozen. With lualatex it works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex\else
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %with pdflatex
\fi

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{eng,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Some article title?},
  journal = {Whatever Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {british},
  editor={D. Editor}
}
@article{fra,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  title = {Un article?},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {french},
  editor={D. Editor}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@hook@initlang{%
 \csq@reset=0 \csq@setstyle{\abx@field@langid}%
 %optional for the colon after "In":
 \ifdefstring{\abx@field@langid}{french}{}
  {\def\FDP@colonspace{}%
   \def\FDP@thinspace{}}%
 }
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Output with lualatex:

[image]

#### Output with pdflatex

[image]

Comment: Nice! Actually, I use XeLaTeX, but it does not work either with it. Guess I will have to look about fixing this JPEG embedded ICC profile issue I have with LuaLaTeX to finally switch over (especially since it also gives font expansion with microtype).

Comment: Small question though: why are single quotes used instead of “”?

Comment: I don't know, but you get them also without the changes (if the language is british). Ask a new question if you want to change this.

Comment: What profile issue have you with lualatex? Can you add a question about this?

Comment: Actually the quotes work correctly (_i.e._ I get “”) in my original document with your solution, so it’s perfect for me. I need to do some more research on that profile issue, but basically I have a JPEG with an embedded profile that renders differently depending on the used software to visualize it, and differently between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX output. I need to find a good example of image with embedded ICC to check which rendering is wrong, I’ll have a look during the week-end.

Comment: Actually that ICC profile issue is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146517/how-to-improve-color-consistency-of-bitmap-pictures-from-native-format-to-target. I’m adding my workarounds to it (found some that work quite well).

Comment: Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479548/56823. Do you think it should be reported somewhere for LuaLaTeX devs to know about it?

Comment: Sorry I do find your posting quite unclear. Do you have a problem or a solution? If you have problem you shouldn't bury it in some old posting. Report it at the right place.

Comment: I have the same problem as the person that asked the linked question: ICC profiles embedded in JPEG files are lost by LuaLaTeX. I also have solutions, but those are workaround: since it works OOTB with XeLaTeX, I would hope the same could be true for LuaLaTeX. Is that more clear to you?

Comment: Well I didn't read everything, the answer from michal sounds as if it should work. In any case the comments here are the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Using `autolang=other` (and loading the `T1` font encoding) does the job:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[british,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{eng,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Some article title?},
  journal = {Whatever Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {british},
}
@article{fra,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  title = {Un article ?},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2019},
  langid = {french},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No it does not, please read my question above. Using `other` will also translate some other part, like cited pages. I can update my MNWE to show the issue if you want.

Comment: Strange… I used it a few years ago for the book of a friend of mine, and I didn't notice problems. However the data were not the same. Yes, I'd like to see the issue, I'l try to look at ait tomorrow.

Comment: Just add `editor = {Ditor, E.},` keys to both entries for instance.