# Why isn't the ICC profile applied?

Tags: color, printing

I generated an image:

[image]

If color management is properly working, you should see this blue (good!), otherwise it will be red (bad…).

However, if I include this image in a PDF, the ICC profile is not correctly printed while other files like https://www.color.org/version4pdf.pdf are printed correctly). I tried with Evince, Okular, Adobe reader (linux & windows version):

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong?

Following [How to improve color consistency of bitmap pictures from native format to target pdf file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146517/how-to-improve-color-consistency-of-bitmap-pictures-from-native-format-to-target) I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
  \let\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
  \define@key{Gin}{colorspacefile}{\def\GPT@colorspacefile{#1}}%

  \patchcmd\Gread@@pdftex
  {\pdfximage\GPT@RuleAttr}
  {%
    \ifx\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
     \else
      \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4}  file{\GPT@colorspacefile}%
      \@tempcnta\the\pdflastobj
    \fi
    \pdfximage\GPT@RuleAttr
    \ifx\GPT@colorspacefile\ltx@empty
     \else
      colorspace \@tempcnta
    \fi
  }%
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{should_be_blue.jpg}\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,colorspacefile={gbr.icc}]{./should_be_blue.jpg}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I also tried this other solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146853/116348 … this is even weirder, the output I get now is really horrible:

[image]

in both Okular and evince… (but it seems to work in Adobe Reader) Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT**

I found a solution using `img2pdf` (https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/, you can get it with `nix-shell -p img2pdf` if you use nix). Then just do:

```
$ img2pdf yourfile.jpg -o yourfile.pdf
```

then, just do `\includegraphics` to include the `.pdf` instead of the `.jpg`. Tested successfully with Okular, Evince, acroread (tested only linux version, but I expect this to work on windows as well). Not working with firefox and chromium (I guess they don't support ICC profiles for PDF).

If you do not want to lose time running these commands yourself, you can install my library `robust-externalize` (also available in recent CTAN), and run (with `-shell-escape`, see doc if you do not want to use shell escape):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode,
  new preset={img2pdf}{
    set compilation command={img2pdf "__ROBEXT_WAY_BACK____IMG_SOURCE_FILE__" -o "__ROBEXT_OUTPUT_PDF__"},
    set template={},
    command if no externalization/.code={%
      \robExtDisableTikzpictureOverwrite\evalPlaceholder{\includegraphics[__ROBEXT_INCLUDEGRAPHICS_OPTIONS__]{__IMG_SOURCE_FILE__}}%
    }%
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includegraphicsICC}{D<>{}O{}m}{%
  \cacheMe[
    img2pdf,
    set includegraphics options={#2},
    dependenciesList={#3},
    set placeholder={__IMG_SOURCE_FILE__}{#3}
  ]{}
}

\begin{document}

Compare:

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

With:

\includegraphicsICC[width=5cm]{should_be_blue.jpg}

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-command-extra-options: "--shell-escape -halt-on-error"
% End:
```

[image]

Yet, I'm curious to understand why the above methods fail.

Comment: the patch is outdated. In a current pdftex.def `\Gread@@pdftex` has a quite different definition.

Comment: I downloaded the top image from the external source, and examined the file. It has this attached color profile: "Microsoft BGR Test Profile - for testing only - ICC profile is ordered RBG, embedded WCS profile will correctly render a BGR image". In other words, the image color is intentionally scrambled. It render blue with color management. Is that what you expected? If I detach the color profile, it renders pink. Maybe the PDF has an attached *icc that contradicts the image?

Comment: @rallg yeah, I voluntarily used a test profile so that it is easy to see if color management is enabled or not. Regarding the attached icc, I don't think it is the case, as if the ICC is on an attached pdf created with `img2pdf`, it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok good to know. But do you understand what is wrong with the luatex version?

Comment: I put another comment, then noticed that you solved the problem. So the problem was not whether Evince or Ocular has color management support (my Linux Evince was built without it). You can also directly convert an image to PDF using Image/GraphicsMagick, if it has Ghostscript support. You can also extract and change the *icc.

Comment: I didn't check that. But /N 4 looks wrong, you have an rgb profile as far as I can see. And `/Alernate` looks like a typo. `\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{i-should-be-blue.icc}%
\pdfximage colorspace \the\pdflastobj {i-should-be-blue.jpg}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage` works ok with pdftex + adobe, but other pdf viewer then don't show anything.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh good job, thanks a lot! just changing `/N 4` to `/N 3` and `Alernate` into `Alternate` fixed it! Thanks a lot! Feel free to write it in an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Btw, how do you know that `/N 3` is good but not `/N 4`? What is it doing exactly?

Comment: rgb uses three values, cmyk four.